# Unable to get response from my JSP application using PayPal PDT

Tags: java, jsp, paypal

I used `PayPal PDT` in my JSP application, the code worked earlier. But now I am not getting any response from the PDT, not even "FAIL"

More clearly, when I `read data` from PayPal website, the `BufferedReader.isReady()` showing false.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I seem to not be able to get PDT or IPN response either.  the request I send to the paypal server for PDT returns the "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" page. Can you confirm what result you are getting from your PDT request? My IPN link isnt even being run since the code there sends me a mail and I am not getting any. But the payment is being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Its PayPal specific problem read documentation provided by PapPay or service integrated providers.

You must be having different response code and their meanings if you are integration your system with third party system.